# Datatype in AdventureWorks database

Tags: sql-server-2008, sqldatatypes, nvarchar, adventureworks

When I looked at the tables in Adventure works, the design of each columns seems a bit strange. Since AdventureWorks shows industrial standards I want to follow it.

In Phone number columns they have given type for the column as 
Phone:nvarchar(25)

1. Why they've add type as Phone:nvarchar(25) ?
2. What's the difference bewteen Phone:nvarchar(25) and nvarchar(25) ?
3. I've tried to manualy type the type of phone column as 
   Phone:nvarchar(25) but it gave me an error. why it gives me an error?

How do I make the phone column of type Phone:nvarchar(25)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a user defined type in the Adventure Works database called `Phone`. If you want to create it yourself, you can do:

```
create type dbo.Phone from nvarchar(25) null
```

Then you can do:

```
create table Contact (id int identity(1,1), name nvarchar(255), phone dbo.Phone)
```

You can see that a column of type `Phone` is an `nvarchar(25) null` column by default. You can use this for shorthand if you have lots of tables or you'd like to have one way to change all `Phone` columns at once. It's a practice--not really a "best" practice unless it's in some special cases.